# htaccess URL masking subfolder to another domain instead of redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect [www.domain.com/folder](http://www.domain.com/folder) to subdomain.anotherdomain.com without change the first url, [www.domain.com/folder](http://www.domain.com/folder). In [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) I have a WordPress site and in subdomain.anotherdomain.com a Moodle site. By that, only [www.domain.com/folder](http://www.domain.com/folder) must have a redirect, not the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) or [www.domain.com/other_folder](http://www.domain.com/other_folder). It can be done? It´s possible?.

In the Worpress site I´ve this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I try with a iframe, but a Google Chrome don´t like that :/ (cookies issues)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both sites hosted on the same http server or on separate servers?

Comment: The sites are in separate servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot somehow keep a URL pointing to one http server visible in the browsers URL bar but make it connect to some other http server. That would be a gigantic security issue.

If you can change the setup such that *both* host names point to the same http server, then what you ask can be achieved by applying simple some internal rewriting rules.

For separate http servers your only option is to use the proxy module the apache http server brings, *if it is installed and enabled* ...

```
ProxyPass /folder https://subdomain.anotherdomain.com
ProxyPassReverse /folder https://subdomain.anotherdomain.com
```

See the documentation of the proxy module for details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

The proxy module can also be used from *within* the rewriting module, but this comes with an optional decrease of speed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.*)$ https://subdomain.anotherdomain.com/$1 [P,QSA,END]
```

Again this is documented in the rewriting module:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: can be done? I read all the link. In the first server (www.domain.com), if I can configure the proxy pass with `ProxyPass /folder https://subdomain.anotherdomain.com
ProxyPassReverse /folder https://subdomain.anotherdomain.com` will work with my 2nd situation, and for my 1st situation will work for default, right? Having only this two servers. And the url dont change? Sorry if I missundertood something. I read a lot, but I dont sure of this. I forget to said, the 1st server have cpanel, where I add the subdomain. Thanks for the replay!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you actually ask in your comment. Yes, using the proxy module to map that second server into the URL namespace of the first server under the prefix `/folder` will work if you are willing to accept the performance penalty. And the URL shown in the client won't change since the proxy setup is transparent to the client. That's why I suggest that approach. I can't say anything about configuration frontends like `CPanel`, never really used such things.

Comment: I assume that you are using a web space provider instead of operating those http servers yourself. That means that you depend on the setup your provider chose. So you will need to find out whether the proxy module is available for you at all.

Comment: First, answering your question, I´ve full access to the 2nd web server (SSH), in the first one, I´ve to try, something are enabled for default. I gave it a try and work how are saying. Great!. But I cant login in Moodle, Now the problem is in the web browser console: `A cookie associated with a cross-site resource`. Two days ago, I try to fix that problem (only for Google Chrome) in Moodle server, without any lucky (waiting an answer in the Moodle forum). Thanks for the replay!

Comment: OK, so the proxy works fine. The issue is that the cookie that applications tries to rely on (who is still using cookies these days?!?) is created for the original host name where the application is served from, but the browser sees the other host name where the proxy rule is implemented. That is a miss match. Check if you can change the cookie definition for the application or get rid of that cookie. Otherwise you will have to implement a more complex proxy setup which modifies the cookie on the fly. Possible, but questionable.

Comment: Moodle is a PHP Web Application. I'm debugging this app to find the place where I can patch the cookie. I found the place where Moodle people are supposed to fix the [issue](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-67175), but I still couldn't fix it.

Comment: Start here maybe, as said it should be possible to manipulate the cookie in the same way as the proxy module rewrites the content itself: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6715